# Window Manager View is not visible

Tags: android

I am using window manager to show a popup from service, but my popup view is not visible. It is blank. Does someone have any idea why this is happening?

I have written `android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` permission in manifest too. My code looks like this.

```
    int LAYOUT_FLAG;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
        LAYOUT_FLAG = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY;
    } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 22) {
        LAYOUT_FLAG = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST;
    } else {
        LAYOUT_FLAG = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE;
    }

    WindowManager.LayoutParams p = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            // Shrink the window to wrap the content rather than filling the screen
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            // Display it on top of other application windows, but only for the current user
            LAYOUT_FLAG,
            // Don't let it grab the input focus
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            // Make the underlying application window visible through any transparent parts
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    // Define the position of the window within the screen
    p.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.RIGHT;
    p.x = 0;
    p.y = 100;

    windowManager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater =
            (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(layoutInflater, R.layout.activity_lock, null, false);

    windowManager.addView(binding.getRoot(), p);
```

Answer (score 2):

It requires 'draw over other apps' permission by the user. Please search in the settings for this permission and allow it for your app.

Answer (score 0):

1.After add manifest

uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"

2.then add in your mainactivity
public void checkOverlayPermission(){

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
            // send user to the device settings
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

3.give allow to draw overlay permission option